# claims are not added in asp.net core mvc project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, claims-based-identity

When the application loads in angular2 I send post request to set user's timezone. the Action looks like that:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SetUserTimezone([FromBody] string timeZone)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity) User.Identity;
    var windowsTimeZone = TZConvert.IanaToWindows(timeZone);

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(User.FindFirstValue(TautekClaimTypes.TimeZone)))
    {
        identity.RemoveClaim(User.FindFirst(MyOwnClaimTypes.TimeZone));
    }

    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(MyOwnClaimTypes.TimeZone, windowsTimeZone));   
}
```

When I put breakpoint at the end of this action I can see that claim is added, but when another action is called the timezone claim disappears. Am I missing something to save the claim??

Comment: Are you refreshing the cookie or the jwt?

Comment: @tmg I'm reissuing cookie